# Moving Coin Collection to Stapled Coin Pockets

Tags: united-states, coins, collectibles

I'm organizing my coin collection into stapled pockets, organized in the special coin sleeves in a binder.  In additional to my previously bulk-stored coins, I have about a half dozen of the blue Whitman coin collection folders.

[image] [image]

My question is whether moving the coins out of the Whitman folders (some of which are in serious disrepair) to the stapled pockets will adversely affect their value?

Comment: This isn't exactly on topic bit... The modern pockets are probably closer to pH-neutral and otherwise nonreactive. If you don't damage the coins in the process of moving them, I can't think of any other reason not to do so. You would undoubtedly get better answers on a website that was focused on the numismatic community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be wary of having coins in containers with cardboard. Ideally you want the coins to be in an airtight envelope made of plastic to minimize any chance of oxidation or reaction with chemicals in the air.

Cheap, retail coins like you would find in a Whitman collection are not generally going to hold value well. Sometimes you can sell a collection and break even if you have a nice complete set, but in general  VF coins with common dates will not appreciate at all.

Investment coins usually are high-priced items that sell for thousands each, not the sort thing you find in Whitman folders.

In general, collectibles are bad investments in the US because IRS rules tax gains as ordinary income. So, unless you sell them under the table or have really low income, you lose a lot of your profit.

If you enjoy collecting, focus on the fun of it, worrying about investment in coin collections is a joy killer.

A Parting Anecdote...

When I was a kid I painstakingly assembled a lot of BU rolls, because that was the hot thing back then. I wrote on them "DO NOT OPEN FOR 10 YEARS". You know how much a 1980 BU roll of Lincoln cents is worth now, 40 years later? $2.00 on eBay. Some days I spend more on lunch than the worth of my entire Lincoln cent collection.

Comment: Did I read "Plastic" ... generally plastic is loosely equal to PVC. This is bad for coins. Mylar is good.

Comment: @Dheer The point of the question is not to get into the details of which particular plastics to use. The site is about money, not chemistry.

Comment: Agreed. For a coin collector, it is difficult to turn a blind eye to a plastic recommendation :) ... so just ignore my comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is primarily opinion based.

It is like predicting what will happen in future, similar to predicting the value of stock. This is interesting topic on a coin discussion forum like [WOC](http://www.worldofcoins.eu/forum/index.php)

> My question is whether moving the coins out of the Whitman folders (some of which are in serious disrepair) to the stapled pockets will adversely affect their value?

Whitman folders are for basic collectors to know what to collect and easily show what is missing. These are not great way to preserve coins. Infact good quality coins should never be put into such folders. There are quite a few ways to store coins, Stapled flips ... now one also gets self adhesive flips. Coin Capsules or Archival grade envelops. It depends on the value of coin and how long you want to store these and where are the coins kept [moisture, humidity, pollutants are bad for coins]

Comment: Reminds me that I have a pile of old coins wrapped in non-archival paper. Nothing valuable I'm sure, but some day I should find out what I've got from a historical point of view.

Comment: @keshlam Hopefully when you get around to doing it, you will fall in love and develop a new hobby of collecting coins :). Paper is bad, very soon [10 years] they will be pile of rust. User a lock and seal Microwave safe boxes or plain glass jars with air tight lid.